# How to make my document secure before freely distribution?

Tags: pdf, ebook

I have scanned a document and saved in my computer in pdf file. I want that document shall be accessible to all i.e. one shall download it, print it and shall use for personal purpose. I want none to use it for business purpose. So on every page of it I like to write my blog name and it is freely available there. Now my question is:

1. How to write it on every page on the scanned document? It shall be properly readable and beautiful. Sometimes scientific journals write there name and down-loader' address on there document. How they does so?
2. Is there any other way to prevent dishonest businessmen?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "businessmen"? In word and acrobat you can do watermarking and you can fill out the meta associated with the document - that's pretty much your best bet. If you're so concerned about people stealing your work, why release it at all? The copyright is yours if you've written it and if anybody "steals" it (different to distributing it with your copyright) you can take that up with them using the relevant copyright laws.

Comment: They have no copyright. Those books were published long ago and currently the publishing agency has no existence! I am trying to make them freely available to all.

Comment: So if it's freely available anyway, what's to stop anyone from releasing it the same as you? Chances are, if you don't go too extreme with watermarking and stuff people will choose to focus on more lucrative opportunities. Believe me, "dishonest businessmen" have way more lucrative opportunities out there than books that are past the copyright phase.

Comment: if there is no copyright (as you believe), then they are free to do what they want with it.

Comment: So wait, you say the files have no copyright on them (public domain), and you are trying to set clauses on what someone can do and can not do with them ? Sorry but it looks like you are the "dishonest businessman" here.

Comment: If the source documents are in the public domain, everyone has the same right to it as you.  All you can try to "protect" is the output format of what you've done with it.  You could just use paper pre-printed with your watermark to print on before you scan it.  That would make it part of the page image.  That might discourage someone from simply selling your output, but you would have to sue them and win to enforce any claim you think you have.  They could just go to the same source and create their own version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one in the history of commerce has been able to prevent dishonest businessmen. Or, for that matter, dishonest customers or governments. We (collectively) get by because most people are pretty honest (whether businessmen, customers, government reps, etc.) and we do after the fact penalties (that is, lawsuits) for the dishonest ones that are found.

There are two ways you can go:

1. Free distribution, asking business/commercial users to pay
2. Some kind of encrypted, DRM distribution with unique watermarks per copy

The first leaves you vulnerable to cheaters and to those whose definition of "businessmen" differs from your own. For instance, I infer you want to allow free distribution to students. Does that include those who are charging for teaching a class? You can think of all sorts of grey areas if you try. You won't prevent anyone from violating your copyright terms, but you may be able to recover damages or impose penalties via a lawsuit. Note that a lawsuit requires effort, expense, effort, and has no guarantee of success.

The second involves a lot of overhead, effort, and expense on your part. Further, the true cheaters will probably be able to get past your efforts at restriction, so your efforts won't be very effective anyway. However, that does allow you to trace the cheaters and makes it somewhat easier to show violations should you go to the expense and effort of a lawsuit.

Comment: The second option will last until someone cracks whatever DRM and removes whatever watermark you put on there. And trust me, there are lots of people who do this, not even because they wish to harm you but just for the challenge.

Comment: I don't see the point personally in going to all this effort to "protect" public domain documents